# 初歩的な質問への回答に、コピペできるようなコードを含めるのはよいことか?

Tags: 討議, 回答の仕方

[C言語の配列に文字列をいれたいのですが](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2599/30)

で、以下の回答が投稿されていました。

> C言語では、 文字列(charの配列)を「=」演算子で代入(コピー)することができません。 最初は strcpy() 関数を使ってみるのが良いでしょう。

「サンプルコードも付けるとより役立つ回答になります」とコメントしようと考えたのですが、「自分で調べる力を付けてほしい」という意図から関数名を出すだけに止めているのかもしれない、と思いあたりました。

回答の意図が実際そうであったかは別として、「初学者には解決の指針だけ与える」という考え方はありでしょうか?

Answer (score 10):

私の考えとしては:

質問者がどういうレベルかは関係なく、Stack Overflowが参考資料として最大限役に立つように考える。質問者はまさに今調べているところなのだから、出し惜しみすることはない。

と思います。その上で回答に何を含めるかについては:

- どちらが役立つかといえば、サンプルコードがある方が役に立つ
- かといってサンプルコードがあればいいわけではなく、なぜそのコードである必要があるかを解説した回答の方が有用である
- SO上の回答として書くには長くなりすぎる時には、「解決の指針だけ与える」で問題ない

と思います。

[image: 解説とコード]

コードがとくに必要ないQ&Aは別にして、上の緑の領域をめざすのがよいと考えます。

補足: 「コードがない回答は役に立たない」というわけではなく、解説だけでもプラス票に値する回答だと思います。「コードがある回答」と「コードがない回答」がある場合に、「コードあり」の方がよい、という位置付けです。

Answer (score 3):

私の意見は単純に言えば、その考え方によって出来た回答が、**回答として成り立っている**なら良いと思います。

つまり、どんな考え方でも回答の参考になればなんでも良いという意見です。
より参考になる回答が出てくるならば、票によって選別されるはずです。

人によって色々な考え方で回答すると思うので、ここで考え方が良い悪いを議論するのは意味が無いと思っていて、出て来た回答を選別することによって最大限質問者の役にたつようにするとよいと思っています。

Answer (score 2):

この手の技術的な場では往々にして「調べもせずに答えを求めて質問する」人が現れます。

そういった質問が続いた場合は、自分で調べてもらうためにも敢えて「答え（コード）」を書かないという気持ちも出てくると思いますが、今回の質問に限って言えば、そういったショートカットの意味は薄く、単純に最近の他言語と同じ記述ができない戸惑いのように感じますので、コードで示してしまった方が良かったと思えます。

何でもかんでも答えを出す事で、安易に「答え」を求める人が増えてしまう懸念はありますが、結局は質問者の評価値や質問内容によって適切と思える回答をする、ということでいいかなと思います。