# 該当分野では基礎的とされる質問への反応

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

スタック・オーバーフロー上で、ある分野においては基礎的とされる事項に関する質問がされた場合、どのような反応が相応しいでしょうか。

この手の基礎的質問に対する態度が、英語版Stack Overflowのそれと異なるように感じています。本家SOでは比較的受け入れられているようですが（質問によっては結構な好スコア）、現時点の日本語版では拒絶傾向が強いように思えます。

具体例として、自身が回答をつけた質問「[Objective-C の Delegateとは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4930/)」を引き合いに出します。

この質問は回答時点で -4 票が入っていました。確かに該当分野では常識的とも捉えられる内容ですが、質問内容は少なくとも本サイトの質問基準を満たせているように思えます。また私自身もObjective-Cには明るくないため、この質問への回答文を作る過程で新たな学びもありました。

このメタ投稿は「ユーザはこのような質問に反対投票をすべきでない」という意見表明ではなく、同種質問への反応に関して議論できればと考えています。

参考：

- [ヘルプセンター > 質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [ヘルプセンター > 良い質問をするには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [ヘルプセンター > 権限 > 反対投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

関連するメタ話題：

- [参加の仕方は一様ではない： もっと大勢のユーザに書き込んでもらうには](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1551/)
- [初歩的な質問への回答に、コピペできるようなコードを含めるのはよいことか?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

英語版は700万質問以上もあり、日本語版は現在約900質問になったところです。そのため、英語版での扱いと異なるのは当たり前と思います。英語版が東京都なら、日本語版はまだ宇和島市ぐらいな都市です。英語版も成長する過程で現在の形やルールになりましたし、当サイトも成長すると同時に進化すると思います。

簡単な質問についての意見は英語版でも異なります。「簡単な質問を受け入れるとエキスパートが逃げる」派もあるし、「簡単な質問を受け入れないと新規ユーザーが来ない」との意見もあります。メインサイトを見ていると受け入れるべき派は強いと感じますが、メタを読むと反対の声が大きいです：

- 受け入れるべき派：[Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)
- 受け入れないべき派：[Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

当コミュニティはどんな質問を受け入れるべきかを自分で決めるべきだと思います。h2so5が言った通り、マイナス票を入れることは「この質問には解決しようと努力した跡がみられない・実用的ではない・分かりにくい」を示しているし、プラス票を入れるのは「この質問には解決しようと努力した跡がみられる・実用的で分かりやすく書かれている」という意味です。それと同時にメタでの討議も非常にいいと思います。

サイト全体で「A類の質問をBしましょう」というルールを設けても、最後にものを言うのはコミュニティによる投票です（ルールにかかわらず）。このような質問を受け入れるのがいいと思う人には下記のアドバイスを与えます：

1. **簡単に見える質問を見つけた場合、非常にいい回答をしてください**

   yohjpが言った通りで、簡単な質問であっても、いい回答があると質問にもプラス票が集まってきます。
2. **質問の改善余地があれば、編集を頑張ってください**

   変換ミス、書式ミスなどがあれば、編集機能で直してください。質問が努力していないような風に見えると、マイナス票が集まりやすいです。

逆にこのような質問が適切ではないと思ったら、いい質問を聞くユーザーを集めて、スタック・オーバーフローで投稿させるようにしてください。または、自分で「このような質問がいい」と思っている質問を投稿してください。いい質問が溢れると簡単な質問に目がいかなくなるユーザーも増えると思います。

Comment: ご指摘通り「当コミュニティはどんな質問を受け入れるべきを自分で決めるべき」に賛同します（英語版SOとの差異を感じたのは、あくまで本メタ投稿のきっかけでした）。英語版metaでの投稿も興味深いですね…とはいえあまりの分量にnon-nativeには辛いw

Comment: @yohjp nativeにもたまに辛いですよ！文量は半端ないですし、人気な投稿は一時間ごとにコメントや新回答で更新されるので、全部読め切れる人がいないです。日本語版でメタの投稿全部読めるので、コミュニティの意見を掴むのは非常に楽です。

Comment: h2so5さん、jmacさんが言及されているように、賛成投票および反対投票の意味を勘違いしているユーザが少なからず存在しているように思います。この辺りの周知が進めば、「基礎的な事柄過ぎる」というだけで反対投票を投じるユーザは減るのかなと考えます。

Comment: @3100 そのとおりです。新しいコミュニティが作成されてから、時間が立たないとコミュニティ内のルールや習慣が固まらないのは普通です。メタで討議しながら成長すると自然に解決すると思いますし、成長するとするほど新しい問題・疑問が現れてきます。一番大事はコミュニティで問題を解決する努力、そしてメタやメインサイトでのコメントや編集で当コミュニティの習慣を広がることだと思います。想定以上にこのコミュニティが素晴らしいので、引き続きよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 意味を取りにくかった箇所を編集しました。推量の割合が大きい箇所もあったので（とくに最後の段落）、意図通りでないところは上書き編集するか、ご指摘ください。

Comment: @ento ありがとう！いつも編集してくれて助かります！

Answer (score 22):

私の意見を上げておきます。一文でいえば；

あまりに当然なことを聞いているからと、質問へ反対投票するその前に、ちょっとだけ立ち止まって。

- 少なくともスタック・オーバーフローの質問基準を満たしているならば、むやみに反対投票をしない態度が好ましく、「賛成投票しない」という態度で十分なはずです。その時点での質問者自身による理解内容が添えてあれば、この質問基準は満たせていると考えます。
- その分野に明るいあなたにとっては常識でも、質問者やその他の初学者には自明じゃないかもしれません。基本概念であるほど、初学者に納得できる説明を**探しにくい**ことが多いです。（他分野での同音異義語などノイズが多かったり、中級者以上への高度な解説であったり）
- 質問の内容と、回答の品質が比例するとは限りません。本家SOをみていると、大したことがない（失礼！）質問に対して、有用かつ詳細な回答が付いているケースも見かけます。このような回答を引き出した質問には、結果的に賛成投票が集まっていきます。

Answer (score 6):

該当の質問は、質問としては成立していると思います。

しかし、反対投票のボタンのツールチップの最初に「この質問には解決しようと努力した跡が見られない」という文面があるので、リサーチ結果を全く書いていない質問には反対投票したほうが良いのかと思いました。

Answer (score -3):

質問へのマイナス票はその質問をクローズする必要があるという意思表示と考えています。

相応の理由なしに投じる必要はないと思います。疑わしきは罰せずという方向です。

Comment: マイナス票とクローズ表は別です。マイナス表の意味は「この質問には解決しようと努力した跡がみられない・実用的ではない・分かりにくい」です。クローズ表は「この質問は当サイトのスコープに当てはまらない（質問内容がはっきりしない・質問の範囲が広すぎる・主観的な答えしか集まらない・プログラミングと関係していない）」です。簡単にいうとマイナス票は「ベクターがあってますが、質は低い」と比較してクローズ表は「質は別にして、ベクターが当サイトの方向合っていない」というニュアンスです。