# 誤字脱字の多い質問はクローズするべきか

Tags: 討議

下記のような質問を見ましたが、誤字脱字が多いだけで特に内容が分からないわけではないように思えます。

参考：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23811/

どうしてクローズされたか分かりませんがクローズされる理由は何でしょうか？
コメントに理由が記載されていないのでよく分かりません。
(こういった突き放したようなクローズもどうかと思いますが……)
自分なりに考えると

1. モジュロで余りを求めるなどは基礎的な質問だから却下？
   参考：[該当分野では基礎的とされる質問への反応](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1595/)
2. 誤字脱字が多く読みづらいから却下？

１については既に議論されているので
２についてですが、修正を促せばいいような気がします。
プログラム初心者や日本語が苦手な人などもいると思いますが、
こういった質問はクローズするべきなのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

下記の討議が、私として今回のことと似ていたと感じたので関連リンクを張っておきます。
回答がつくということは理解できる方がいると言う事なので、それはそれでいいと思いますし、
回答がつかず、読み手が混乱するということは修正が必要だと思います。
……どちらにしても、クローズするのに指摘しない理由にはなりませんが

[この質問は条件が曖昧で、一旦クローズすべきではないでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2176/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

修正を促すコメントがないという問題提起については同意します。

クローズについては質問の意図が十分明確であるにもかかわらず誤字脱字のみを理由に行われたのであれば不当と考えますが、この質問については誤字脱字よりも

- 質問者がどのような動作を意図しているのか明らかでない
- 疑問点が具体的でない(コードを代わりに書いてくれ質問)

のほうが問題で、質問者の意図を反映しない雑多な回答が集まる可能性が高く、妥当な処置だと思います。

---

「コメントで指摘した上で改善が見られない場合にのみクローズすべき」という意見については、姿勢としては私もそのようにした方が良いように思います。

(レビューでは改善の提案がされていない質問へのクローズ票は基本承認しないようにしています)

ただ、雑多な回答を集めやすい質問については、改善を待っている間に回答が集まってしまい、その中でたまたま質問者の意図に合ったものがあり質問が改善されないまま承認されるようなことになるとQ&Aリソースとしては価値が低いままとなってしまいます。

余りに質が低い質問については、とにかくクローズして改善を待ち再オープンとなってしまうのは仕方ないかなと思います。

Comment: 該当の質問に対してのコメント拝見いたしました。 どの点に対しクローズ票が入っているのか分からなかったのでそういうことだとは納得しました。　個人的には`ゴード`(コードの記載ミス？)などから日本語が得意でない方かと勝手な想像をしますが、そういう方に「書けて当たり前なのだからクローズ票」ではなく「行き成りクローズを投じるよりも先にコメントで指摘をしてあげて、改善の余地が見られないならクローズするべき」だと私個人としては思いますね…

Comment: クローズ票を入れた者です。質問者が抱えた問題について情報が少なすぎる、実際の回答に「欲しいコードは、このようなコードでよかったでしょうか？」と記載されているように、回答側が質問内容をくみ取ってああでないか、こうではないかと推測して考える必要があるため、クローズ票を入れました。ただし、suzukisさんのようなコメントがなかった点については安易すぎたと思いました。